# D3 transition, margin-top does not proceed smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

If you go to [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dDPqvwCEisivyTVmDmct?p=preview), you can see that `margin-top` starts at `25%` and then I try to

```
.transition().duration(3000)
    .style("margin-top", "1%")
```

But, the input drops down to the bottom before coming back up. I wonder why that happens.

Comment: P.S.  Could you re-write the question so that it stands more on its own (without having to click through to Plunker)?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting puzzle.  A couple different details in the d3 code -- each designed to make transitions more flexible -- are conspiring to ruin your perfectly simple transition.

The [`transition.style()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#style) method uses `getComputedStyle` to figure out the starting value for the transition, even if you had set the style explicitly inline or with d3.

The problem with that is that the browser automatically [converts percentage values to pixels when determining the results of `getComputedStyle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/cascade.html#computed-value).  So although you intended to do a straight-forward calculation from `25%` to `1%`, the actual transition that d3 tries to calculate is between something like `124.75px` to `1%`.

When interpolating any value that isn't a simple number (or a colour), d3's [string interpolation method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_interpolateString) is used.  The interpolator identifies all numbers in the before and after strings, and transitions them, but for the rest of the string, it just substitutes in the "after" value.

So for the transition from `124.75px` to `1%`, the *numbers* transition from `124.75` to `1`, but the *unit* flips immediately from `px` to `%`.  Result?  Your element suddenly jumps from having `margin-top: 25%` to `margin-top: 124%` (or thereabouts) before transitioning down to 1%.

The work-around is to calculate the pixel-length of 1% margin yourself (remembering that % values for top and bottom margins are calculated relative to the parent container's width), and use that as your final value for the transition.  Then, after the transition is complete (in an `each("end", function)` call), re-set the margin in percentage values so that it will be responsive if the window resizes.

Comment: would a jQuery calculator also work? Could you expand upon the each function call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "JQuery calculator" -- if it converts between percent values and pixels, then it sounds good.  You can find out more about the [each/end call in the API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each); the usage I'm proposing is pretty simple, something like `.each("end", function(d,i){ d3.select(this).style("margin-top", "1%"): });`

Comment: By jQuery calculator, I mean you could use jQuery to get the page hegiht, then make your own calculation (.01 * height).

Comment: P.S.  Another option (instead of converting from percentage to pixels), is to [use a custom tween to directly transition the percentage values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#styleTween)

Comment: You could use JQuery or getComputedStyle to get the page/container *width*, not including padding, and then calculate the percentage from that (margin and padding percentages are always relative to width, so that `margin-top:5%` is the same thickness as `margin-left:5%`).

Comment: Another reason to use jQuery (or a Tween) is that it can be responsive.